# RainMeter multiline - RegExp

Tags: regex, readfile, rainmeter

I'm trying since a couple of days to read an entire file with Rainmeter.

I'm working with WebParser and RegExp.

My result is something like this:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

If I make a RegExp like `(?m).*`, I have only the first line. However, if I use something like `(?m).*\n.*`, I have the two lines...

Fantastic, but sometimes, I just have 1 line and sometimes, I can have 5 lines. If I'm writing = `(?m).*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*` and I have for example just 3 lines, Rainmeter doesn't get my lines.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a singleline option to force the `.` to match newline symbols:

```
(?s).*
```

As an alternative, you can add anchors matching at the beginning and end:

```
\A(?s).*\z
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CA(%3Fs).*%5Cz&i=I%20have%20%0D%0Aseveral%20lines%0D%0Ahere.)

Unless you need to access some specific lines, you do not need the multiline flag that makes `^` and `$` anchors match at the start/end of a *line*.